# Is there a point to creating a folder inside the public folder?

Tags: reactjs

I'm extremely new to React & recently found out about the %PUBLIC_URL% stuff.

Generally, what is the point of using the url?
Also, it seems kind of messy putting a lot of images/json/etc in one place, so I was wondering if there was any point to creating an img folder inside the public folder: ex. public/img and accessing it like: %PUBLIC_URL%/img/img1.jpeg.
Would that mess anything up?

I've done some research about it but I'm kind of dumb so I don't really see the point of using PUBLIC_URL over just accessing the public/ folder.

From https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder, it says:

> If you put a file into the public folder, it will not be processed by webpack. Instead it will be  copied into the build folder untouched. To reference assets in the public folder, you need to use an environment variable called PUBLIC_URL.

Honestly I don't know what this means; could someone explain? Sorry for all the dumb questions <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Put assets you use from javascript inside your source folder, either in a specific folder (`src/img`) or next to the javascript files that use them. Use `public/` for files referenced in your html, with `%PUBLIC_URL%` to keep create-react-app happy.

Ideally you'll want all assets and files used in your javascript inside the `src` folder. This way you can `import` these files and create-react-app will make sure you have a valid url to them.

Files in your public folder can't be `import`'ed from javascript! You'll want the public folder for any assets that you need from html directly (favicon, manifest.json, robots.txt) or you just want to be able to link to them (I sometimes have a logo.png in there so I can use that url on other websites).

The PUBLIC_URL is required for assets in `public/` because create-react-app needs to insert the path in case you serve your app in a nested path. for example, `https://youdomain.com/myapp/v2/index.html`, would have a public url `/myapp/v2`. This needs to be set in your package.json, but if you don't serve from a subpath you don't have to change anything.